# Adding tabs to Android 5.0 toolbar?

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar

I am in the process of creating my first app and learning java for the first time as well, and am stuck on creating tabs on the toolbar..

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534211/how-to-create-toolbar-tabs-with-viewpager-in-material-design) post. However I was still confused on how to properly implement them. Should I be downloading the `SlidingTabsColors` file, and then adding it as a dependency in `gradle.build`?

In this section: `fragment_sample.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I can not add `com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout` to the layout.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

For a better implementation try:

add this to your gradle dependences

```
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
```

Then instead of the `SlidingTabLayout` use

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

In your activity where you want to call the `ViewPager` You have to

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
 pager.setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
 PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

You might want to implement your adapter like this:

```
public class YourCustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private String[] titles = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
    public YourCustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
           case 0:{
              return new YourFragment();
           }
           case 1:{
              return new YourFragment();
           }
           case 2:{
              return new YourFragment();
           }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!